# Missing library on 64 bit riscv Fedora

Tags: fedora, qemu, glibc, riscv

I am working on an assembly-based Forth (on top of Linux - https://github.com/mcmenaminadrian/riscyforth) for Risc-V and I can build it and run it on my real 64 bit hardware (a Nezha SBC running a Debian-based install).

I decided to test it also on QEMU with Fedora but it won't run:

```
[root@fedora-riscv riscyforth]# ./riscyforth 
-bash: ./riscyforth: No such file or directory
```

This seems to be because I am missing a library:

```
readelf -a ./riscyforth 

....


   Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000010040 0x0000000000010040
                 0x0000000000000150 0x0000000000000150  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000190 0x0000000000010190 0x0000000000010190
                 0x000000000000000d 0x000000000000000d  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld.so.1]
```

And my understanding this is a 32 bit library - but my OS is 64 bit:

```
[root@fedora-riscv riscyforth]# uname -a
Linux fedora-riscv 5.10.6-200.0.riscv64.fc33.riscv64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 12 13:46:56 UTC 2021 
riscv64 riscv64 riscv64 GNU/Linux
```

And, rather more importantly, so is the ELF:

```
[root@fedora-riscv riscyforth]# readelf -a ./riscyforth | more
ELF Header:
   Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
   Class:                             ELF64
   Data:                              2's complement, little endian
   Version:                           1 (current)
   OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
   ABI Version:                       0
   Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
   Machine:                           RISC-V
   Version:                           0x1
   Entry point address:               0x10690
   Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
   Start of section headers:          98992 (bytes into file)
   Flags:                             0x5, RVC, double-float ABI
   Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
   Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
   Number of program headers:         6
   Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
   Number of section headers:         23
   Section header string table index: 22
```

I have updated the Fedora install and rebooted (as there was a mix of -33 and -32 packages before) but this has not fixed the issue.

Why do I need to install a 32 library and which one do I need to install? I cannot find an obviously titled RPM.

Or do I need to put something in the Makefile for Fedora that I don't need on the Debian system?

Comment: I fixed the immediate problem with ln -s /lib/ld-linux-riscv64-lp64d.so.1 /lib/ld.so.1 but I still hope someone can answer *why* I needed this. I also don't get the downvote without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> This seems to be because I am missing a library:

You are not missing a library, you are missing the ELF interpreter (`/lib/ld.so.1`), also known as the dynamic linker or the loader.

> And my understanding this is a 32 bit library

I am not sure what "this" in your statement refers to; your binary is definitely 64-bit, and couldn't use any 32-bit libraries in any case.

> Why do I need to install a 32 library

You don't.

It appears that normally `/lib/ld.so.1` should be present on a RISC-V system and be a symlink to `/lib/ld-linux-riscv64-lp64d.so.1` (at least on GLIBC-based systems).

So your QEMU target environment is missing required parts.

> I fixed the immediate problem with `ln -s /lib/ld-linux-riscv64-lp64d.so.1 /lib/ld.so.1` but I still hope someone can answer why I needed this.

Because you somehow didn't install GLIBC into your QEMU environment properly.

Comment: I used the supplied RPMs - so something wrong with the packages?

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin The packages work fine on the real hardware, so it's unlikely that there is anything wrong with them. But whatever procedure you used to install them into the QEMU (and you haven't supplied any details on what you did here) didn't work.